# Why is my Unsupervised Individual Deduplication rule failing to stop duplicate creation?

Tags: civievent, duplicate-contacts

I've seen a number of questions on this site suggesting that there may be problems with the deduplication rules, e.g.:
[Why am I getting duplicate contacts for contributions?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20961/why-am-i-getting-duplicate-contacts-for-contributions)

My individual unsupervised rule checks against first name, last name and email address. No length is set for any field, all have a weight of 10, and I've set the threshold at 25. When I run this rule as an administrator it successfully finds the duplicate records, although the results list present the 'Threshold' as '30' when I display that column, which seems rather odd (maybe it is reporting the score rather than the threshold?).

But when users are registering for events through the standard registration form, duplicate contacts are consistently being created.

How can I ensure that my unsupervised dedupe rule works as I expect it to?

Running CiviCRM 5.13.5 on Drupal 7

Comment: I'm getting reports of this too. We're also on 5.13.5. I'll report back if I get anywhere investigating.

Comment: I found this bug https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/961 and this seems to apply in our case, as we commonly include fields to capture an email address for the participant and a billing email. So an update may resolve the issue. Any one know which version this bug fix went into?

Comment: The issues comments mention it going into 5.17

Comment: @Graham, the issue seems to be addressing a very specific case but I think this issue goes much deeper. We are having the same issue in searching for duplicates as you describe above. and it is the same whether it is a general rule or unsupervised rule. I tried with and without field length, played with thresholds. even put 'Contact Id' as the field to match on (which should be impossible) but getting the same result everytime