# Automated New Individual Merge

Tags: contacts, joomla, duplicate-contacts, individual

I am entering "CContacts > Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts > Add Rule for Individuals". I'm adding rules to prevent creating new individual records for both phone and email. However, no matter how much I try, the new individual records still open, and the system does not give any warning. I only had a question about it, but the instructions there didn't help me solve this problem. This is probably related to the number system we use in our country. However, the problem was not solved as a result.

---

We do not use CiviCRM in a different project. We use a very simple system written by one person. If there is an individual record and the system is trying to create a new record with the same information, it automatically outputs the old record. This prevents double registration. Is there a way to do this.

We do not use an area code initially when adding the phone number to the profile. It does not start with 0 and writes it all together. A total of 10 characters have been written. Like 5321234567.

---

Let me give you some details for this.

For example;
name: conqueror
Surname: ates
Phone number: 5321234567

I created a new individual with knowledge. After me, a new individual is created with exactly the same information as above. I want to stop this. In this way, the recording should not be prevented or the old ID should be written on the screen or the information on that ID should be shown automatically even if the registration has been made. Otherwise, I have to combine more than 500 pairs of individual records per week.

---

And now I get the following error.

backTrace

0 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
1 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(833): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("İstenen web sayfası yüklenemedi. Web sitesi web tarayıcısı ayarlarından çerez...")
2 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(828): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKeyCommon()
3 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKey()
4 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(206): CRM_Core_Controller->key("CRM_Contact_Form_Contact", TRUE, FALSE)
5 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller/Simple.php(66): CRM_Core_Controller->__construct("Kişi Ekle", TRUE, NULL, "CRM_Contact_Form_Contact", TRUE, FALSE)
6 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(78): CRM_Core_Controller_Simple->__construct("CRM_Contact_Form_Contact", "Kişi Ekle", NULL, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
7 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(263): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contact_Form_Contact", "Kişi Ekle", (Array:1))
8 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
9 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
10 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
11 /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
12 /public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402): require_once("/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
13 /public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
14 /public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
15 /public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
16 /public_html/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(196): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
17 /public_html/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
18 {main}

---

I'm not the only one with this problem. There are a lot of people who are experiencing the same problem as me and reporting the problem. Why is there no improvement in this matter?

[Why is my Unsupervised Individual Deduplication rule failing to stop duplicate creation?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31920/why-is-my-unsupervised-individual-deduplication-rule-failing-to-stop-duplicate-c)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking a question like this.

Merging of duplicate of contacts is a difficult process for a system like CiviCRM. Becasue CiviCRM is used in different countries and in different organizations. Each one has it is own rules who is a duplicate.

1. The first difficulty is to identify who is a duplicate.
2. The second difficulty is to merge those contacts.

Regarding 1, say if you record households and household members and you identify duplicaties with the same e-mailaddresses. What to do about people in a household who share an e-mail address?

Regarding 2, say for example you two records, one is called joe smith, the other Joe D. Smith. The difference is the capital and the middle name. Which one do you want to keep and which one could be overiden.

What I am trying to say it that the answers to those question differ from organization to organization using CiviCRM.

That said some automation is possible but that also depends on how contacts are entered into your system. Do they come from a CSV file, manually entered by a back office user, from a webform, from a contribution form or from the API. 
If you use a webform or a contribution form you can set up deduplication rules and use those rules in your webform or contribution form. 
If entered manually the user will receive a popup indicating possible duplicate contacts.

My experience, as a CiviCRM consultant, is that many organizations have some kind of manual process to once in a while manually merge duplicate contacts.

Comment: Hi @Jaap , All contacts are created via "Create New> Individual". The people who create them are the people I create through Joomla.

Comment: But I have a bigger problem right now.
I've set the phone number to "Length 10, Weight 10 and Weight Threshold to Consider Contacts 'Matching': 10".
At the moment when I want to create an individual by adding a phone number, the site gives an error like the one above. I also get an error when I try to delete a record with a phone number attached.

Comment: I erase this rule I created. Still, the problem is not solved.

Comment: Could this be the same problem as the question you refereed to? Did you find out whether that issue still exists or whether this is different? CiviCRM is an open source system and there is no supplier who supply a fully functional product.

Comment: Error in the records where I added Phone Number occurred after changing the rule weight values. Before the record was being created there was only double. Cannot be created at this time.